# In Ruby on Rails, routes.rb, if map.something will create something_path and something_url, does map.connect create something like that too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, named-routing

In Ruby on Rails, routes.rb, if we create a "named route"

```
map.something ":a/:b", :controller => 'foobar'
```

it will also create `something_path` and `something_url` which are two methods usable in the controller and in the view. Does `map.connect` create something like that too?  Otherwise, isn't `map.connect` somewhat disadvantaged in this way?  I checked that `connect_path` and `connect_url` both aren't created automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your thinking. `map.connect` does not create `something_path` and `something_url`. This is the purpose of named routes like `map.something`: To create "names," hence the name "named routes."

Comment: in that case, url and path still exist... is there a quick to get those values?

Comment: You can try creating helper methods (in app/helpers/application_helper.rb) for generating the paths/urls you use often.

Comment: No. That is the entire point of Rails Named Routes. If you need the path, you use a named route. If you don't care, you use connect.

Answer (score 0):

A named route can be thought of as a named `map.connect` route. `map.connect` just establishes a route that points to an action within a controller. But it would be a pain to call the route again and again everywhere. Using a named route is more readable. The advantage of `map.connect` is that it can be made to connect to any controllers action. If you read the routes.rb file carefully you see that the following two statements have the lowest priority:

```
Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

If you comment out the above two lines you will not be able to reach any route except for the ones that you define using named routes/resources.